# pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'soapuiProperties'

Tags: java, maven, soapui, pom.xml

I am using Cucumber in a Maven project in Eclipse to launch SoapUI.

My POM.xml file works quite well when running from within Eclipse, the test completes with no errors.

However, when I launch from the command line with   "mvn test"   I get this error:

pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'soapuiProperties' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n    \r\n    ..

Here is the POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Project_name</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project_name</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
        <artifactId>ready-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://java.net/projects/maven-repository/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!--Adding SoapUI Maven plugin-->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                         <name>soapui.home</name>
                         <value>C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI\bin</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>    

    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>        
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
                    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                    <tasks>
                        <copy file="pom.xml"
                              tofile="${project.build.directory}/ready-api-maven-plugin-${project.version}.pom"/>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${assembly.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/public-pom.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>         
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!--  <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test
                    </phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test
                        </goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>C:\\Users\\charles\\test-automation\\Soapui\\Project_name-REST-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions> -->
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Any idea how I need to fix the POM ?  I tried moving the SoapUIproperties block into and out of the  pluginrepsositories block, but there result is the same.

Comment: What is this `soapuiProperties`? What its use?

Comment: Please fix your pom according to the official documentation https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html , or explain what special things are you trying to do! As it is, it simply does not make sense.

Comment: I have tried various POM files from the soapui web site and none of them worked for me, I have worked up a custom POM with the help of a local developer.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'soapuiProperties' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n \r\n ..

means that you've malformed POM file (pom.xml). In other words you have placed `soapuiProperties` tag in the wrong place.

You need to move `soapuiProperties` to `build/plugins/plugin/configuration` for `soapui-maven-plugin`. So here is the snippet of how correct pom.xml should look like:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>soapui-tests.xml</projectFile>                    
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.logroot</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/soapui-logs/</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `soapuiProperties` is not a valid child of the `pluginRepository` element.

The `pluginRepositories` section declares where `maven` will attempt to find and download plugins from.

It does not appear that you are making use of the SoapUI plugin so you can probably remove the `pluginRepositories` section.

The placement of the `soapuiProperties` suggests that it is not being used by the test so you can probably remove it.